# RelayCommand not executing when the xamarin forms nuget package upgraded

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, nuget-package

i am using RelayCommand for one of command, it was working fine Xamarin.Formns nuget package 2.3.3.180, but when i upgraded the  Xamarin.Formns nuget package to 3.1.0.637273, the RelayCommand is not triggering. am using MVVM light. Any help around for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are running into a closure issue, but it's hard to know without seeing your code. The MVVMLight RelayCommand uses a weak reference internally to help avoid memory leaks, but it doesn't support closures. You can pass true in the 'keepTargetAlive' argument to see if this fixes the issue.